# Novice in Sikuli

Tags: macos, testing, automation, windows, sikuli

I am new in using Sikuli for my Windows App and OSX app Automation. I see various variants of Sikuli available out there.

1. Sikuli-api
2. SikuliScript.jar
3. SikuliX

My task is to automate Windows/OSX app using sikuli and run those tests over my continuous deployment environment.

In that Situation, I would want to learn which option of Sikuli I should use. Which of the above three are more latest and has much support?

Comment: SikuliX will be better

Comment: what error you are getting up on adding the dependency? check if the dependency got downloaded to your local repository?